# Can if statements be refactored to boolean operators like !=, ==, && and ||?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, boolean, refactoring

Can this be refactored into boolean? `board` is an array and `move` is and index. `position_taken?(board, move)` should return `false` if `board[move]` is `" "`, `""` or `nil` but return `true` if `board[move]` is `"X"` or `"O"`.

```
def position_taken?(board, move)
  if board[move] == " "
    false
  elsif board[move] == ""
    false
  elsif board[move] == nil
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `board[move]` guaranteed to equal `" "`, `""`, nil, `"X"` or `"O"`? If so, you *could* write `!board[move].to_s.strip.empty?`, but that's a hack that I could not recommend (it only works because `nil.to_s #=> ""`). If `board[move]` equals some other value what is to be returned?

Comment: Yes. `board[move]` is guaranteed to equal `" "`, `""`, nil, `"X"` or `"O"` and no other value.

Comment: With active support you can just use `board[move].present?`

Answer (score 7):

Since you have less and simpler positive cases I would test for the opposite:

```
def position_taken?(board, move)
  %w[X O].include?(board[move])
end
```

It will handle invalid values differently than your original approach but it does directly what the method name suggests: check if the position is taken (instead of checking if the position is not not taken).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `none?` and pass `board[move]` to be compared:

```
[' ', '', nil].none?(nil) # false
[' ', '', nil].none?('')  # false
[' ', '', nil].none?(' ') # false
[' ', '', nil].none?('t') # true
```

Comment: nice. but this syntax I think is for ruby >= v2.5 .x ?

Comment: Ya!, you're right, is from 2.5+. Otherwise, it'd have to be used with a block.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what your method is doing without knowing what you will pass as board argument so the best I can demo is just a string:

```
str=''
!!(str && !str.strip.empty?)
#=> false

str='a'
!!(str && !str.strip.empty?)
#=> true

str='   '
!!(str && !str.strip.empty?)
#=> false

str=' '
!!(str && !str.strip.empty?)
#=> false

str=nil
!!(str && !str.strip.empty?)
#=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is logically equivalent:

```rb
def position_taken?(board, move)
  !(board[move] == " " || board[move] == "" || board[move] == nil)
end
```

If any of the conditions are true, it will be inverted and return false. If all of the conditions are false, it will be inverted to true.

---

You could also put the strings you want to match against in an array and use something like `!include?` or, if you're using `ActiveSupport`, you can use `exclude?`.

```rb
def position_taken?(board, move)
  ["", " ", nil].exclude?(board[move])
end
```

Comment: the internals make sense for string matching but do we know what data type is passed for board?

Comment: do you need comparison for nil? why not `!board[move]`

Comment: @lacostenycoder `!board[move]` would work but the double inversion might be hard to follow. You could also use `board[move].nil?`.

Comment: `exclude?` is an active_support method. `!include?` might work without using Rails.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this code should be refactored to:

```
def position_taken?(board, move)
  not board[move].to_s.strip.empty?
end
```

Comment: This probably doesn't matter but this has slightly different behavior than the original code because of `strip`. For example, `"  "` (two spaces) would return `true` in the original code but `false` in this implementation.

Comment: @ScottBartell it’s tic-tac-toe; `board[move].length == 1` is always true.

Comment: Haaa, well that makes a lot of sense... Didn't realize it was tic-tac-toe.

Answer (score 1):

If only X or O is allowed, Why don't you specify them in the condition like this:

```
boared[idx] == 'X' || board[idx] == 'O'
```

I think it is much better for readability and simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
def position_taken?(board, move)
  !case board[move]; when " ", "", nil; true end
end
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this answer? [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22537574).

Comment: It just a negated `case`-construction. Nothing particular to explain about.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. It can be refactored to this:

```
def position_taken?(board, move)
  board[move] != " " && board[move] != ""
end
```

Comment: that returns true if `board[move]` is `nil`